# Understanding an OR statement in someone else's macro that applies title case to text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro from a course on Microsoft Word VBA that applies title case to text (i.e. capitalises every word except words like "the", "to", etc.) I'm trying to understand the instructor's reasoning but he usually doesn't respond to questions from what I see on the forums.

I've reproduced his code below. Basically, it creates an array of words that should not be capitalised, compares each word in the selection to that array, sets blnOmit to "True" (i.e. omits the word's first letter from being capitalised) if there is a match, then capitalises a word "If blnOmit = False Or i = 1 **Or i = Selection.Words.Count**" (5th line from bottom).

I don't understand that line of code, i.e. capitalise a word if "i = Selection.Words.Count". I thought this would make the last word in the selection always capitalised, even if it actually shouldn't be capitalised. But when I ran this macro, it works perfectly, i.e. the last word is not capitalised if it shouldn't be capitalised. And when I deleted the "i = Selection.Words.Count", the macro did not work at all - nothing was capitalised.

Can someone explain why my guesses were wrong please? And how does the i = Selection.Words.Count work in this macro? Thanks!

```
Sub TitleCase()
Const strOMIT As String = "a, about, above, across, after," 'omitted rest of string for his privacy
Dim astrOmit() As String
Dim rngWord As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim blnOmit As Boolean

' Create array of words which should not be capitalized
astrOmit = Split(Expression:=strOMIT, Delimiter:=", ")

' Process each word in selection
For i = 1 To Selection.Words.Count
    Set rngWord = Selection.Words(i)
    blnOmit = False

    ' Compare word to each word in array
    For j = LBound(astrOmit) To UBound(astrOmit)
        If LCase(Trim(rngWord.Text)) = LCase(astrOmit(j)) Then
            blnOmit = True
        End If
    Next j

    ' Capitalize word if necessary
    If blnOmit = False Or i = 1 Or i = Selection.Words.Count Then
        rngWord.Case = wdTitleWord
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why you deleted the "word-vba" tag please? I thought it would help people find this post. Although I also used "ms-word" and "vba" as tags, people looking at the ms-word tag might not necessarily have VBA experience, and likewise those looking at the VBA tag might be better versed in Excel VBA.

Answer (score -1):

Some of this is opinion (which is discouraged on this site) but...

"it works perfectly, i.e. the last word is not capitalised if it shouldn't be capitalised"

Let's say the last word you can see in the Selection is "about". However, let's say the next thing after "about" is the end of paragraph and that your selection includes the whole paragraph. Then the last item in Selection.Words will in fact be the paragraph mark. So "about" is not the last word and will not be capitalised.

As for why the author chose to put "Or i = Selection.Words.Count" in the condition, it's pure speculation but perhaps if you are capitalising a title you might want

A Story about Something

but

Nothing Much to Shout About.

In an ideal world, what would actually happen is that whoever specified the function would spell out exactly what it was supposed to do (and perhaps why). Yes, it is true that we can see from the code that there is a special case, and you can work out what it actually does. But that doesn't tell you what it is *supposed* to do. So anyone trying to test this routine could not know whether it was behaving as it should or not.

"And when I deleted the "i = Selection.Words.Count", the macro did not work at all - nothing was capitalised"

When I did that here (deleting the preceding "Or" as well) it failed also, except then I realised nothing was selected. Once I'd selected something, the code worked as expected. Perhaps you had a similar problem?

It doesn't look as if it was the objective of this particular piece of code to discuss "coding style" but personally I prefer to bracket up the separate terms in a condition, e.g.

```
If (blnOmit = False) Or (i = 1) Or (i = Selection.Words.Count) Then
```

If you're working with VBA all the time and know all the rules about how operators combine, precedence rules etc., you may not need this, but it is helpful for anyone who has to dive in and support the code. Suppose, for example, someone accidentally deleted slightly more than the "Or I = Selection.Words.Count""part and the line ended up as

```
If blnOmit = False Or i Then
```

I wonder how many VBA coders would be confident they understood what that actually means without looking up the rules. It's not a syntax error!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know Selection.Words.Count included paragraph marks. I still don't know why the instructor included "OR i = Selection.Words.Count". It does not cause the last word to become capitalised, I tried the macro and it gave "Nothing Much to Shout about". And you're right that the macro works if I delete "OR i = Selection.Words.Count", thanks for highlighting that I probably forgot to select some text earlier. Unsure if off-topic, but when would you need to know about operators combining/precedence rules in VBA? I've not encountered those before.